# error PLSQL creating procedure with exception

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to create a procedure in PL/SQL and I receive the following error:

```
Errors: PROCEDURE BORRAR_PELI
Line/Col: 10/1 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:
   ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null
   pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
   json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array***
```

My procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE borrar_peli(delete_id peliculas.id%TYPE)
IS
corrupto EXCEPTION;
precio_dia_v peliculas.precio_dia%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT precio_dia INTO precio_dia_v FROM peliculas WHERE id = delete_id;
  IF precio_dia_v > 4 THEN
  RAISE corrupto;
  ELSE
    DELETE FROM películas WHERE id = delete_id;
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN corrupto THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('es corrupto');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error code ' || SQLCODE || ': ' || SQLCODE);
END;
```

Comment: I did a cut-and-paste of your code, modified it a bit (as I don't have your tables), and it compiled without any error. Are you sure there are no hidden chars in the END IF that you have? or are you copying the code from Windows to Linux, and getting CRLF in the process?

Comment: do you like this procedure from a trigger ? i have such a problem when i call a procedure from trigger and in the same time select and delete data from a table , i find the solution put PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION in the declare section , you can see the datail in this link : https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonomous-transactions